# Text not loading properly in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, fonts, text

On my Ubuntu 18.04 system, the menu texts are not highlighted as they used to be earlier. I don't know what happened- any change in a file, etc. that this problem has occurred. The following images will help you understand the problem better:

[Text is not highlighted as it used to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMMk9.png)

[On hovering the options, the text gets highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrsqr.png)

[This problem is occurring in all the menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXe5m.png)

[Check this one also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQgLs.png)

I couldn't attach images due to less reputation. Please check by clicking on the links. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Have you recently changed your graphics drivers or installed a new theme? I would advise that you check the theme settings and maybe change them, and also make sure that you have the recommended packages and drivers installed for your GPU in `Software & Updates`.

Comment: From what I can see in the screenshots, the texts are there, but they are of almost the same colour as the background colour. So, try changing the theme using `Gnome tweaks`.

Comment: @Puspam I don't know what has happened to my gnome tweaks. It is not opening whenever I click its icon. It loads, but it does not open up.

Comment: Try purging the gnome-tweaks package and again install it.